# How can I find and remove multiple classes of particular element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I select an element with multiple classes?

```
$('#nav').find('.open').removeClass('open');
$('#nav').find('.current').removeClass('current');
```

How can I do this in a better way?

Comment: Put all the classes you want to remove in one call to removeClass, separate them with spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate [selectors using `,`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)  and use [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) with space separated classes.

```
$('#nav .current,#nav .open').removeClass('current open');
```

or

```
$('#nav').find('.current,.open').removeClass('current open');
```